# Content Deployment 

Tags: 2007

We have two environments Staging and Production, We have a feature to activate Content  Types and PageLayouts. Once this has been activated in Stage there was lot of modifications on the PageLayouts, now its sits in the database with newer versions and and also added new pagelayouts. Now the newly added Page layouts are not in the feature

We took the Wsp as it is and deployed it in Prod environment

Now we did an incremental deployment, Now all the feature got activated , with the PageLayouts with only version 1.0, It did not consider all the versions in the Database.

Can somebody Let me know what will be right approach in this scenario

Thanks in Advance

Thomson

Answer (score 1):

This is by design. Content Deployment only deploys the highest Draft and the highest Approved version.

Comment: Can you let me know what is the best way in this scenario?